# XenServer - Removing Blade Server from Chassis

Tags: xen, xenserver, blade-server, pool, blade-chassis

I've got to **remove** one of our PowerEdge M620 blade servers from our M1000e Chassis server to look at the hardware on the server, mainly the mezzanine card installed.

- Will **removing the blade server from the chassis** remove the server from the ***resource pool*** I've created?
- When I **put the blade server back** in the chassis, will XenServer act as if the server has just been **shutdown** the whole time?

I have yet to remove the servers from the chassis while they're members of the resource pool so I figured I'd reach to see if anybody has done this before, or something similar with other servers belonging to a resource pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**: Yes, the pool will simply not see the server for a while.

You need to migrate all VMs off that pool member to others, and if you lack resources then some less-important ones need to be shut down to make room.

No need to remove server from pool or anything, just do a normal shutdown and eject the blade from the chassis once its off/off.

When you power it back on (ASSUMING none of the hardware has changed) then it will fire up, go into maintenance mode for a few  minutes, and then rejoin the pool like normal and show up live in xencenter.